# React-Router-v4 Not Working on Preact via Babel Register

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, isomorphic-javascript, preact, babel-register

I am trying to setup an server rending react using react-router-4. While it works just fine on the front-end side (Webpack). It appears that `preact-compat` is not working when used in the server side. I am using `babel-register` so transpile the code.

[image]

I have a branch here for reference:
https://github.com/abarcenas29/preact-sandbox-v0/tree/wip/isomorphic-react

to run:
`yarn run install`
`yarn run start:prod`

go to `localhost:3100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Babel to alias a dependency doesn't make sense, because Babel does not run on your dependencies (in node_modules).  Use something like module-alias instead.

Full answer to the same question is on Github: https://github.com/developit/preact-compat/issues/390#issuecomment-304334947